# boost asio and libcurl mutiple handler

Tags: boost, libcurl

im learning libcurl and boost:asio from this nice post http://www.lijoantony.com/?p=76

though i do have one question about the source code at:

[sample code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lijoantony/4098139/raw/asiohiper.cpp)

the main function looks like:

`int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GlobalInfo g;
  CURLMcode rc;
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  memset(&g, 0, sizeof(GlobalInfo));
  g.multi = curl_multi_init();
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, sock_cb);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA, &g);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, multi_timer_cb);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA, &g);
  new_conn((char *)"http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/331.79/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.79.run", &g);  /* add a URL */
  /* enter io_service run loop */
  io_service.run();
  curl_multi_cleanup(g.multi);
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\ndone.\n");
  return 0;
}`

i see there is no place calling the curl function curl_multi_perform()

how does the tasks get started at the very begining?

Answer (score 0):

> I see there is no place calling the curl function `curl_multi_perform()`

This is because this sample code uses an alternative API called [`curl_multi_socket_action`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html):

> `curl_multi_socket_action` is then used instead of `curl_multi_perform`.

*(see the MULTI_SOCKET section of the [official documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) for more details)*

> how does the tasks get started at the very begining?

The *magic* occurs thanks to the `CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION` option, [`curl_multi_add_handle`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_add_handle.html) function and corresponding timer logic.

If you refer to the `static void new_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g )` function you can see that:

```
static void new_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g )
{
  /* ... */

  rc = curl_multi_add_handle(g->multi, conn->easy);
  mcode_or_die("new_conn: curl_multi_add_handle", rc);

  /* note that the add_handle() will set a time-out to trigger very soon so
     that the necessary socket_action() call will be called by this app */ 
}
```

So in practice everything starts by calling `new_conn(...)` which in turn will trigger `multi_timer_cb` which then calls `timer_cb`.

And `timer_cb` performs the `curl_multi_socket_action`.